# The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm having trouble with this stored procedure. I've researched and been over it a few times, so I'm guessing I'm just missing something obvious. If I try and actually remove any part of the Select list, then SSMS gives me the same error. If I leave them equal, then VS debug gives me the error. I'm a little confused about that one. The majority of the procedure is as follows -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Billing_Misc_Update_Test]
(
@ID as  varchar(100), @CandidateID as varchar(100), @EntryType as varchar(100), @Amount as money, @EntryDate as smalldatetime, @InvoiceBillingDate as smalldatetime, @ClientKey as varchar(100), @BillingMemo as varchar(100), @UserID as varchar(100), @RegBilled as varchar(100), @OTBilled as varchar(100), @RegPaid as varchar(100), @OTPaid as varchar(100), @chkStatus as varchar(25)  )

-- This is an insert
if @ID = 0 
Begin
    If not exists (select 1 from AccoutingReports with (nolock) 
                    where Verify = @CandidateID 
                      and BillingDate = @EntryDate 
                      and InvoiceBillingDate = @InvoiceBillingDate
                      and BillingMiscType = @BillingMiscType

                    )
    Begin
    if @EntryType = 'Expense' or  @EntryType = 'Bonus' or @EntryType = 'other'
    Begin
        Insert into AccoutingReports ( 
                        [BillingDate], 
                        [ConsultantName],  
                        [HoursWorked],  
                        [OTHoursWork],  
                        [HoursBilled],  
                        [RegHoursBilled],  
                        [OTHoursBilled],  
                        [PayDollars],  
                        [BilledDollars],  
                        [RegBilledDollars],  
                        [NegBilledDollars],  
                        [OTBilledDollars],  
                        [NegOTBilled_Dollars],  
                        [MedicalCost],  
                        [FicsSutaSS],  
                        [PerDiem],  
                        [PerDiemPay],  
                        [COGS],  
                        [GrossProfit],  
                        [GrossMargin],  
                        [CommissionPercent],  
                        [CommissionSales],  
                        [CommissionRecruiter],      
                        [Verify],  
                        [BurdenPercent],  
                        [ClientKey],  
                        [W1],  
                        [W2],  
                        [EarnedDays],  
                        [VacationDays],        
                        [Memo],    
                        [TSDate],  
                        [isImported],   
                        [BillingMiscType],  
                        [BillingMiscMemo],  
                        [InvoiceBillingDate],  
                        [InvoiceStatus])    


                    Select  
                        @EntryDate,  
                        'Updated By UserID: ' + @UserID,  
                        0,   
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        @amount, 
                        @amount, 
                        @amount, 
                        @amount, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0,  
                        @CandidateID, 
                        0, 
                        @ClientKey, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        @BillingMemo, 
                        getdate(), 
                        0,  
                        @BillingMiscType, 
                        @BillingMemo,  
                        @InvoiceBillingDate,  
                        @chkStatus
    End Else
    Begin
        Insert into AccoutingReports ( 
                        [BillingDate], 
                        [ConsultantName],  
                        [HoursWorked],  
                        [OTHoursWork],  
                        [HoursBilled],  
                        [RegHoursBilled],  
                        [OTHoursBilled],  
                        [PayDollars],  
                        [BilledDollars],  
                        [RegBilledDollars],  
                        [NegBilledDollars],  
                        [OTBilledDollars],  
                        [NegOTBilled_Dollars],  
                        [MedicalCost],  
                        [FicsSutaSS],  
                        [PerDiem],  
                        [PerDiemPay],  
                        [COGS],  
                        [GrossProfit],  
                        [GrossMargin],  
                        [CommissionPercent],  
                        [CommissionSales],  
                        [CommissionRecruiter],      
                        [Verify],  
                        [BurdenPercent],  
                        [ClientKey],  
                        [W1],  
                        [W2],  
                        [EarnedDays],  
                        [VacationDays],        
                        [Memo],    
                        [TSDate],  
                        [isImported],   
                        [BillingMiscType],  
                        [BillingMiscMemo],  
                        [InvoiceBillingDate],  
                        [InvoiceStatus])    


        Select          @EntryDate, 
                        'Updated By UserID: ' + @UserID,  
                        convert(money, @RegPaid) + convert(money, @OTPaid), 
                        @OTPaid,  
                        convert(money, @RegBilled) + convert(money, @OTBilled),        
                        @RegBilled,        
                        @OTBilled,             
                        (convert(money, @RegPaid) * @payrate) + (convert(money, @OTPaid) + @PayRate),  
                        (convert(money, @RegBilled) * @BillRate) + (convert(money, @OTBilled) + @BillRate),                   
                        0,                  
                        0,                  
                        0,                      
                        0,              
                        0,             
                        0,          
                        0,             
                        0,       
                        0,              
                        0,              
                        0,                    
                        0,                  
                        0,                      
                        0,  
                        @CandidateID,              
                        0,    
                        @ClientKey,     
                        0,     
                        0,             
                        0,               
                        0,  
                        @BillingMemo,   
                        getdate(),           
                        0,  
                        @BillingMiscType,     
                        @BillingMemo,  
                        @InvoiceBillingDate,  
                        @chkStatus 
    End
        Select RowsUpdated = @@Rowcount, Error = 'New Entry: Transaction Successfull'
    End Else
    Begin
        Select RowsUpdated = 0, Error = 'Entry Already Exists'
    End 
End Else
Begin
    If not exists (select 1 from AccoutingReports with (nolock) 
                    where Verify = @CandidateID 
                      and BillingDate = @EntryDate 
                      and InvoiceBillingDate = @InvoiceBillingDate
                      and BillingMiscType = @BillingMiscType
                      and ID <> @ID
                    )
    Begin                       
    if @EntryType = 'Expense' or @EntryType = 'Bonus' or @EntryType = 'other'
    Begin
        Update AccoutingReports 
           Set [BillingDate] = @EntryDate
             , [ConsultantName] = 'Updated By UserID: ' + @UserID
             , [HoursWorked] = 0
             , [OTHoursWork] = 0
             , [HoursBilled] = 0
             , [RegHoursBilled] = 0
             , [OTHoursBilled]   = 0             
             , [PayDollars] = @amount
             , [BilledDollars] = @amount
             , [RegBilledDollars] = @amount
             , [NegBilledDollars] = @amount
             , BillingMiscType = @BillingMiscType
             , BillingMiscMemo = @BillingMemo
             , InvoiceBillingDate = @InvoiceBillingDate 
             , InvoiceStatus = @chkStatus
         where ID = @ID
    End Else
    Begin
        Update AccoutingReports 
           Set [BillingDate] = @EntryDate
             , [ConsultantName] = 'Updated By UserID: ' + @UserID
             , [HoursWorked] = convert(money, @RegPaid) + convert(money, @OTPaid)
             , [OTHoursWork] = @OTPaid
             , [HoursBilled] = convert(money, @RegBilled) + convert(money, @OTBilled)
             , [RegHoursBilled] = @RegBilled
             , [OTHoursBilled]   = @OTBilled             
             , [PayDollars] = (convert(money, @RegPaid) * @payrate) + (convert(money, @OTPaid) + @PayRate)
             , [BilledDollars] = (convert(money, @RegBilled) * @BillRate) + (convert(money, @OTBilled) + @BillRate)
             , [RegBilledDollars] = 0
             , [NegBilledDollars] = 0
             , BillingMiscType = @BillingMiscType
             , BillingMiscMemo = @BillingMemo
             , InvoiceBillingDate = @InvoiceBillingDate 
             , InvoiceStatus = @chkStatus
         where ID = @ID
    End
        Select RowsUpdated = @@Rowcount, Error = 'Update Entry: Transaction Successfull'
    End Else
    Begin
        Select RowsUpdated = 0, Error = 'Entry Already Exists'
    End 
End
```

The ID generally results to 0, and the `EntryType` I've been starting with is Bonus. So it should run the very first block of insert/select statements, but gives an error.

Worth noting that the change I've made was to add a new column InvoiceStatus to the table AccountingReports to store chkStatus as a `varchar(25)`. After adding this new column to the table, and amending the insert/select statements, it's giving me this error. I'm pretty lost so any advice would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: The only problem I see is after your procedure parameters you needs a `AS BEGIN ... SP Guts ... END`

Comment: There are only two insert statements in here. Separate them from your procedure and run them by themselves. Some decent formatting would make debugging this a lot easier. When you cram insert statements with lots of columns onto 2 lines it makes debugging and support a lot more difficult.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg The syntax should be accurate as I'm just modifying a SP that worked ok before. I was just trying to get it to fit Stack Overflow's grey coding box requirements.

Comment: @SeanLange It should only be running the first one. I've poured over it, and the fact that it all worked fine before adding the InvoiceStatus column leads me to believe its some macro level error, and not necessarily a comma or a small syntax issue. Regardless, I've followed your advice, and can edit it in accordlingly.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg `@BillingMiscType` and `@payrate` are undeclared, too.  SQL Server doesn't parse this code.

Comment: @BaconBits you're right, would that be affecting it? I don't believe it was before. It seems the brunt of the error is in adding an extra column, the code totally trips up after that. If I delete it, the code works fine (assuming I comment out inserts into a non-existent column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating another table in the database, and a second insert/select statement that would put the same ID + Candidate ID and then the filtered chkstatus column with the parameter. I don't know why the original solution wouldn't work, but this was a fairly simple workaround that shouldn't take too much away from the ideal solution. Cheers!